# How to know if a file in a CIFS network drive is locked from Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, command-line, windows, cifs

I've mounted the following network drive in Ubuntu:

```
//192.168.1.11/shared /media/shared cifs credentials=/home/guest/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

This `//192.168.1.11/shared` folder is used by Linux systems (Ubuntu 14+) and Windows systems (7+).

The problem that I have is that I need to know when a file is locked from Windows systems with bash scripting. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "locked"

Comment: Being edited by someone else.

Comment: I don't think Windows stores information about open files on the disk itself. There are locking mechanisms like those used by Office, which stores a file called `.~lock.filename#` with the user name and hostname of the user currently editing the file. Those could be easily found by a single command. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah @Jos, that's what I meant. But where are those files stored at? Are they stored at the user's side or at the network drive?

Comment: The lock files Office uses are stored in the same directory as the file itself. If the user opens a file from a network drive, the lock file is stored on the network drive as well, and is visible from Ubuntu. You can locate these with the command `find /media/shared/ -name .~lock*`.